# Autodesk Forge viewer for .dwg fileș

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

The Autodesk forge viewer, from the learning samples, does not seem to have a 3d viewing option when opening a .dwg file. Is there a way to view a .dwg file in 3d rather than just a plan view? A shading option would be useful as well as many .dwg files contain solids.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Autodesk.DocumentBrowser extension to switch between views if you can see 3d views listed in the model derivative manifest of the DWG file.

```js
viewer.loadExenstion('Autodesk.DocumentBrowser');
```

Here is an example of the look of the `Autodesk.DocumentBrowser` ext for a Revit file. You may see a similar tree structure while using it with DWG files.

[image]

Or you can modify [your viewable filter](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/#step-2-load-model-in-manifest) to obtain 3D viewables only instead like this way:

```js
​var viewables = viewerDocument.getRoot().search({type:'geometry', role: '3d'});
viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, viewables[0]);
```